# is there any difference between where company_id=1 and where company_id='1' in oracle?

Tags: oracle, where-clause

If I am enclosing bind value within single quotes in where clause, Am I doing a mistake?
I just want to know is it good practice to put every value under single quotes? 
Is the second one have any side effects in terms of query performance?

1.`where company_id=1 and subscriber_id=50 and person_name='Chetan'`

2.`Where company_id='1' and subscriber_id='50' and person_name='Chetan'`

Might be this is a silly question as I am new in the database so please guide me.

Comment: First off, you're not enclosing a "bind" value - you're enclosing a literal value. Something enclosed in single-quotes is defined as a string, so if you do `where number_datatype_column = '1'`, you force Oracle to have to convert the `'1'` into a number, i.e. `1`. It is much better to use the correct datatypes when comparing two values, so that you avoid the implicit conversions. Number to string conversions aren't too bad, but when you compare a string column (e.g. with a datatype of VARCHAR2, etc) to a number, Oracle will try to convert the column's values to a number.

Comment: Thanks @Boneist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If data-type of your `company_id` column is numeric like INTEGER, NUMBER, DECIMAL, etc. you should NOT use single quotes.

 If data-type of your `company_id` column is character like CHAR, VARCAHR, VARCAHR2, etc. you MUST use single quotes.

Same thing applies to your `subscriber_id` column as well as any of other columns inside any of your tables.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why shouldn't we use single quote if column is of type Integer/Number/Decimal. '1' this might become a string/char but wouldn't sql execute this company_id='1' without an error

Comment: As Boniest mentioned in his comment, if you use single quote like '1'  to compare numerical columns, your query will have an overhead of oracle implicit type conversion before comparison. This can be painful in terms of performance when you have tons of data in your table and you are firing significantly large queries. You can consider this as one of the Best Practices.

Comment: I saw the comment now, okay got the point. Though the comment is about Oracle. Is this same with MSSQL as well?

Comment: Yes. In general for almost all the databases. Though you can check documentations of the specific database you are using.